# Download pdf from REST API with correct encoding

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, pdf, encoding

I'm trying to download pdf file from rest api using those two methods:

```js
download(): ng.IPromise<Blob> {
    return this.$http.get<ArrayBuffer>(this.urls.getUrl())
        .then(response => {
                return new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
              }
        )
}
```

```js
this.service.download().then( file => {
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
            url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        open(url)
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'invoice';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function() {
              document.body.removeChild(a);
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 0);
}
```

And there appears to be some problem with the encoding of created Blob. If I call this endpoint from Postman and select "save response" then "save to a file", I get the correct pdf. When I use the presented code, file seems to be incorrectly encoded (opened with vim has generally similar structure, but different symbols).

Answer (score 0):

In service you can use httpOptions like this:

```
   download() {
    const httpOptions = {
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(
      ServerUrl + `/api/getfile`,
      httpOptions
    );
  }
```

also on you component you can call service and download the pdf like this:

```
this.api.download().subscribe(
  (idata) => {
    let blob = new Blob([idata], { type: 'application/pdf' 
     });
    var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(idata);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = downloadURL;
    link.download = 'invoice.pdf';
    link.click();
  },
  async (err) => {
    
  }
);
```